# Как посчитать для записи кол-во месяцев с момента вставки до заданной даты?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Как посчитать для записи в таблице, что запись появились в таблице уже как N месяца от заданной даты?

Например, запись в таблице появилась 29.01.2010, а заданная дата выгрузки из таблицы 28.03.2010.

По идее, хочу чтобы у таких записей проявился флаг, что у записи с момента вставки на момент выгрузки идёт 3-й месяц. То есть, запись появилась в январе, считаем январь за месяц, потом февраль за месяц и март за месяц, итого - идёт 3-й месяц.

Пробовал через `ADD_MONTH` и `MONTHS_BETWEEN`, но в результате получаю 2-а месяца.

Comment: *к примеру запись в таблице появилась 29.01.2010* И где именно это отмечено? и как? Покажите пример данных (в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов) - пара записей, требующих пометки, и пара н требующих.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С функцией `MONTHS_BETWEEN` всё правильно, с `29.01.2010` до `28.03.2010` прошло неполных два месяца:

```
select abs (months_between (date'2010-01-29', date'2010-03-28')) months from dual
/

    MONTHS
----------
1,96774194
```

Но если считать так: сегодня загружны данные - идёт первый месяц, следующий месяц - идёт второй месяц, послеследующий - третий и т.д., то реализовать счётчик месяцев надо так:

```
with t (created, offloaded) as ( 
    select date'2010-01-29' dt1, date'2010-03-28' dt2  from dual
) 
select extract(month from offloaded) - extract(month from created) + 1 monthcount 
from t
/

MONTHCOUNT
----------
         3
```

Comment: 0xdb, решение про 2 месяца мне понятно,  а мне как раз таки надо считать, что идёт 3 месяц с даты появления записи: т.е, январь, февраль, март.

Comment: @Badma Посмотрите, это то, что вы ожидали?

Comment: Да, ок, сначала не так посчитал.)